# Excel vba combobox additem overflow

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, overflow

I'm trying to add 80 items to a combobox witch is a list from 500 to 40,000 with steps of 500 (500; 1,000; 1,500; 2,000;...; 39,500; 40,000). The problem is that it makes an overflow. Is there a way to get around it?

Here's my code:

```
i = 1
j = 500
For i = 1 To 80
    Me.cbx_6.AddItem j
    j = j + 500
Next
```

Thanks for your time.

-Vincent

Comment: How did you declare `i` and `j` ?  They should both be `Long`   If you let them default to `Integer` then the max value they can hold would be about 32,000

Comment: OMG @TimWilliams it was this simple ... i'm probably too tired for this lmao. Thanks for your time it was simple as that.